# How to save recent searches on Google Places Autocomplete for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-places-api

Is there a way to save my recent searches on Google Place Autocomplete iOS controls, and show them on the result controller, on the initial load?

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface ViewController ()  
{
   NSMutableArray *arrMutData;  
}

- (void)resultsController:(GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController *)resultsController didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place{
   arrMutData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  [arrMutData addObject:place.name];
}
```

In the above delegate method for Google Place Autocomplete you will get the recent search. You can add recent searches in an `NSMutableArray`. 
And, show them on the result controller on your initial load.

Comment: So we will have to handle it ourself right? The SDK has no recent searches feature?

Comment: Yes, you need to handle it own your own. Currently, SDK does not provide any such feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
 func resultsController(_ resultsController:
 GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: 
 GMSPlace)
  {
             resultArray.append(place.name)
  }
```

this is delegate method of Google Place Autocomplete.. i hope it will help u..